# Page redirect if i enter direct url and Session expire

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am creating a webpage with password protected.
all is working well but my problem is whenever a user copy a url from my webpage and  paste another browser then that page displays same data(i have a number of webpages and all pages displays related data). that is not i want. i want that is automatically goes to login page again. and i need same session expire script 
my code is shown below.

```
<?php



$host = ""; // Your host address to your     database on your server. Usually "localhost". Check with your hosting provider
$user = ""; // Your username you set up for this database on your server
$pass = ""; // Your password you set up for this database on your server
$db = ""; // The database name that you will be connecting to

// Connecting to the MySQL database
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);


if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // Query to check to see if the username and password supplied match the database records
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND     password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    // If login information is correct
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) 
    {
    header('Location: done.php');

}
    // If login information is invalid
    else {
    header('Location: error.php');

}
}

?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: 1st of all never use `mysql_*` it is outdated. start using `mysqli_*`. 2nd i don't see where your `session_start()` and `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` is. you cant start session without those things.

Comment: you can use cookie for it or have session ticket service using some encryption for it...

Comment: first of all, your english isn't helping to understand the issue and it seems like u need to use session object, start the session somewhere with session_start() and store logged in users details in it and you can destroy it with session_destroy() and when u visit the page again, you must check the session and if it is not set then u can redirect the user to the login page

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`Session`][1] for that. An example is here.

soon after the user enters login credentials

```
    if (valid credentials given) 
    {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['data'] = "some data";

    }
```

Then in every page you need to use these two statements.

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['data'] is set and valid) {
   // go to the page
}
else {
   // go to login page
}
```

I recommend you to go through a [good tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) on how to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the avaiable session data at the start of your page

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] || $_SESSION['expires'] < time() ){
    header('Location: login.php');
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    exit;
}
else $_SESSION['expires'] = time() + 3600; //refresh the lifetime
```

And then during your login you shall set these variable:

```
<?PHP
//Never sent unchecked data to mysql server
//creating md5 hashed to prevent from mysql injections
$username = md5(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE MD5(LOWER(username)) = "'. $username .'" AND MD5(password) = "' . $password . '"';
 [...]
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) === 1){
     $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
     $_SESSION['expires'] = time() + 3600;   // 3600 seconds session lifetime
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$host = ""; // Your host address to your     database on your server. Usually "localhost". Check with your hosting provider
$user = ""; // Your username you set up for this database on your server
$pass = ""; // Your password you set up for this database on your server
$db   = ""; // The database name that you will be connecting to
// Connecting to the MySQL database
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // Query to check to see if the username and password supplied match the database records
    $sql      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "' AND     password='" . $password . "' LIMIT 1";
    $res      = mysql_query($sql);
    // If login information is correct
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        // if user is valid then start session
        if (session_id() == '') {
            // session isn't started
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = true;
        }
        header('Location: done.php');
        die();
    }
    // If login information is invalid
    else {
        header('Location: error.php');
        die();
    }
}
// done.php
if (session_id() == '') {
    // session isn't started
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['user']) {
        // valid code
    } else {
        // redirect on login page
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of complete login system that store login information in session. Try this!

**Login Page**

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Login Check Script**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**Success Page**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

**Logout Script**

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every page that needs a logged-in user, has to check individually, whether the user has enough privileges (is already logged in). If he does not have enough privileges, then redirect him to the login page.

*secretPage.php*

```
session_start();

// is user not yet logged-in?
if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
  // remember the requested url
  $_SESSION['loginTarget'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

  // redirect to the login page
  header('Location: login.php', true, 303);
  exit;
}
else
{
  // already logged in
  echo 'hello user';
}
```

*login.php*

```
session_start();

// user submitted the login input?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  ...
  // after checking username and login
  if ($usernameAndPasswordAreCorrect)
  {
    // remember the logged-in user
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userId;

    // redirect to the target page
    header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['loginTarget'], true, 303);
    exit;
  }
}
...
```

This script is only an example to explain the workflow, not a working solution, it should get you started. There are a lot of other things to do, like hashing passwords with a slow key-derivation function ([BCrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)), input validation, preventing SQL-injection, setting a deault login target...